# How to override css in blogger?

Tags: html, css, blogger

i would like to somehow override blogger's `css` because my code does not actually looks like it should on my blogger page. Actually it looks good but dropdown menu is not working.
this is the [code](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LEWzJY)
this is how [it looks](http://mybetablog2002.blogspot.com/)

Comment: You've not actually asked a question. What is it you are wanting to override? Simply write new CSS to override previously declared CSS.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you want to copy something but make your own changes to it in the CSS to override the original CSS instructions you can use !important to do this e.g.

background: #eeeeee !important;